# Ansible: conditional in task, or in template?

Tags: ansible

It seems there are two ways to make a file content dependent on a variable.

```
copy:
  path: /foo
  content: |
    {{ if myFoo }}
      ; lots of stuff
    {{ else }}
      ; lots of other stuff
    {{ end }}
```

Or I can do

```
copy:
  path: /foo
  content: |
      ; lots of stuff
when: myFoo
```

and

```
copy:
  path: /foo
  content: |
      ; lots of other stuff
when: not myFoo
```

What is the normal construct here? What's desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rewrite the tasks.

```
- copy:
        dest: /tmp/ansiblefile.txt
        content: |
          {% if myFoo %}
            ; lots of stuff
          {% else %}
            ; lots of other stuff
          {% endif %}
```

```
- copy:
    dest: /foo
    content: |
      ; lots of stuff
  when: myFoo

- copy:
    dest: /foo
    content: |
      ; lots of stuff
  when: not myFoo
```

In my opinion, either is fine. However, I would use the latter approach since I find it easier not to deal with jinja templates; the documentation for jinja templates is not very detailed and easy to follow.

Comment: The only potential issue with this latter example is a case where both conditional tests could be true. As you have indicated, 'not myFoo' and 'myFoo' should work fine, but how someone interprets and creates this could introduce problems. I always prefer a single 'if > then > else' in a single function, instead of separate functions that have no relationship to the state of the other. But that's just my $0.02.